# MsAccess subform current record highlight

Tags: vba, ms-access

MsAccess by default highlights the current record of a subform with a different background color than defined in Section.Backcolor or Section.AlternateBackcolor.
Is there a possibility to change the color of the default record or disable the automation provided by MsAccess?

Thanks
Regards

Comment: Hello SnupiX, welcome on SO, I would say that you can't disable it BUT you can change the color of default using vba or conditional formatting.

Comment: Thanks TourEiffel for your replay, but I have no condition to take advantage of conditional formatting. All row of the subform are related at the same data or item in the form.

Comment: i think you should leave it as it is. Even passing by vba would not full fit your needs.

Comment: Probably it is so. I thought there was a possibilty to set some option. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Be a bit creative:

1. Add an unbound textbox that fills the entire Details section
2. Name it as txtID
3. Set the border and the background to transparent
4. Set Enabled to False and Locked to True
5. Set format condition rule to: *Field value* - *Equals to* - *[ID]*
6. Set format condition to set: Background colour and Foreground colour
7. Add this code to the *OnCurrent* event of the form:

```vb
Me!txtID.Value = Me!Id.Value
```

Result example (unique field ID is hidden):

[image]

Comment: Sorry Gustav, I forgot to specified that I use DataSheet not Continuous Forms

Comment: Oh. Then you are out of luck.